# How can I get a Vault 101 Children's Jumpsuit

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-3

I'm on a [mission](http://twitter.com/johnrudy/status/21533559361) to [collect](http://twitter.com/johnrudy/status/21533594462) as many [unique items](http://twitter.com/johnrudy/status/21533611219) as I can. Why? I can't say, but probably some bizarre form of OCD.

Anyway, in this hunt, using the lists provided at [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_101_Child%27s_Jumpsuit), there is the Vault 101 Children's Jumpsuit. How can I collect this as an adult player, seeing as it goes away after you turn into a teenager, and there don't seem to be any kids in Vault 101 upon your return?

Note: I'm on an XBox 360, so anything involving the console won't work for me. However, for the sake of completeness, whoever gets here first with the console commands to do it for PC users, go for it. I just won't upvote (but I'm sure others will).

Comment: Base ID: 000340f2 on the page you linked. That'd make it 'additem 000340f2' wouldn't it?

Comment: @Raven: For our PC-using friends, yes. :) I'm asking if there's a way to get that bugger on a console (specifically XBox 360) edition. :) I'd say drop an answer for it; even though I won't upvote (I need an answer for me!), I'm pretty certain the rest of the community will in support of the complete answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child%27s_Vault_101_Jumpsuit), the jumpsuit is only accessible as a child, unless certain console cheats are used. *(There were actually [two](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Child%27s_Vault_101_Jumpsuit) [different](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_101_Child%27s_Jumpsuit) pages for the same item.)*

Also, there is a great [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/939933-fallout-3/faqs/58568) available over at GameFAQs, detailing the method to get each unique item, *including those only availble trough glitches* (and it is even for the Xbox360)

Now, for those  wanting the jumpsuit anyways, on a console enabled version, you can simply type `player.additem 340F2 1` in the console

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I don't think you can actually find it. The only jumpsuit I have found were the Vault 77 jumpsuit (found at paradise falls in the slaver barracks on a shelf with a note near it),
the Red Jumpsuit (if you kill Red in Big Town), the armored 101 vault Jumpsuit (given to you by Moira at the very beginning of the game) and finally the Handyman Jumpsuit (you have to kill Haley (at Haley's hardware).
They are all unique items. But I think the children jumpsuit cannot be found. Maybe it's only mentioned as description text. The game is full of unimportant info (but they help  to create the setting) :)

Hope to been useful. ;)

Comment: You don't need to kill Red to get her suit/headband. After you rescue her and Shorty from the Police HQ, use the option to "Give her a weapon" and just take it from her inventory. You can also fast travel back to your house (with them in tow) and deck them out with Raider or other armour you don't wear, and weapons you don't use often. Its always hilarious to go to Big Town and see a raider and a Talon merc wandering around

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to kill Red to get the jumpsuit. Once you rescue her, you have the option in the dialogue to give her a weapon. At that time, you can take her jumpsuit and put any outfit you have in your inventory on her. Be careful though, once you get her safely to Big Town, she will wear that outfit for the rest of the game and you will not be able to get it back. However, you can change Red's outfit at any time before you get her back to Big Town. Try this tip: Give Red an armored suit if you have one, and begin escorting her back to Big Town. When you know you are close to Big Town, initiate a conversation with her and you can take the outfit back, and/or put her in any outfit you want... the sexy nightwear, perhaps? Ha ha ha.